# PostgreSQL - Update an array's values to the distinct union of its elements and elements of another array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm facing a problem, updating an array's elements with non-existing values from another array.

To be concrete, consider the following table `tbl1` which looks somewhat like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|   c1  |   c2  |   c3  |   c4      |
+-----------------------------------+
|   A   |   B   |   C   | [1, 2, 3] |
|-----------------------------------|
```

Let's say that I want to update the column `c4`, with the following data: `[2, 3, 4]`.
I expect the updated value of `c4` to be `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

So far, I tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO 
    tbl1 (
        c1, c2, c3, c4
    ) 
VALUES ....
ON CONFLICT (c1, c2) DO UPDATE
SET c3=EXCLUDED.c3,
    c4=(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(ARRAY_CAT(c4, EXCLUDED.c4)) AS x) AS s)
```

However, the query doesn't seem to be legitimate.
I get a syntax error when executing it, stating that I can't use `SELECT` inside a `SET` statement.

I also have several limitations:

1. I must update the value `on conflict`
2. I can't create helper functions in the DB
3. It has to be a single query

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
insert into the_table (c1,c2,c3,c4)
values ('A', 'B', 'new', array[2,3,4])
on conflict (c1,c2)
 do update set 
     c3 = excluded.c3, 
     c4 = (select array_agg(distinct x order by x) 
           from unnest(the_table.c4||excluded.c4) as t(x))
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=941fe6c7270b4a9e05aa3dd6abb4e7af)

A `null` value in the INSERT part leaves the original array unchanged, because `array[1,2,3]||null::int[]` yields `{1,2,3}`. If you don't want that, you probably need some CASE expression in the update part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(id INT primary key, arr int[]);
INSERT INTO Foo(id, arr) values (1, array[1,2,3]);

INSERT INTO Foo(id, arr) VALUES (1, ARRAY[2,3,4]) 
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO UPDATE SET arr = (
  with T AS (
    -- Make a table out of existing array value
    SELECT unnest(arr) FROM Foo WHERE id=EXCLUDED.id
  ), S AS (                        
    -- Make a table out of new array    
    SELECT unnest(EXCLUDED.arr)
  ),                                
  -- Union both tables and aggregate back to array
  R AS (
    SELECT array_agg(unnest) AS arr FROM (
      SELECT * FROM T UNION SELECT * FROM S
    ) U
  )
  SELECT arr FROM R
);
```